# Magento extend cms block class

Tags: magento

I'm trying to extend the magento class Mage_Cms_Block_Block. I've got my module active. I think the reason why its failing is to do with the config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config> 
    <modules>
        <VisibleBlocks_ShowBlocks>

            <!-- The version of our module, starting at 0.0.1 -->
            <version>0.0.1</version>

        </VisibleBlocks_ShowBlocks>

    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <mage_cms>
                <rewrite>
                    <cms_blocks>VisibleBlocks_ShowBlocks_Block_Border</cms_blocks>
                </rewrite>
            </mage_cms>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Can someone explain to me what the tags inside the global tags mean? Can the tags inside rewrite be called anything?

Answer (score 4):

OK seems that asking the questions made it clearer to me. Hope this hasn't a waste of time for anyone. 'mage_cms' should be 'cms' as that is the module i'm extending and 'cms_blocks' should be 'block'.

Answer (score 0):

i have explain the details,please check

```
 <global>
            <blocks>
                <cms><!--module name of rewrite class mage_cms -->
                    <rewrite>
<!-- file path of Block of app/code/core/mage/cms/block.php -->
                         <blocks>VisibleBlocks_ShowBlocks_Block_Border</blocks>
                    </rewrite>
                </cms>
            </blocks>
        </global>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <cms>
                <rewrite>
                    <block>VisibleBlocks_ShowBlocks_Block_Cms_Block</block>
                </rewrite>
            </cms>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>`

With these tags, we say we will configure a block of Magento’s core called  cms  and we will rewrite () the « block » block of this module

Also make sure your module is active & being displayed in system/config/Advanced